# InitializeComponent() Cannot locate resource based on system language

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, mvvm, initializecomponent

The application was developed on machines running windows 10, with the system language set to our local language, danish. Now we are at a stage where the software needs to be used in offices in other countries.
However, the view crashes on startup on those machines, and I have found out that if I change the system language on my own machine, it will not work for me either.
Why this is, we can't figure out.

Error message from InitializeComponent:

> *System.IO.IOException: 'Cannot locate resource 'views/main/mainview.xaml'.'*

StackTrace:

> *at MS.Internal.AppModel.ResourcePart.GetStreamCore(FileMode mode,
>   FileAccess access)    at
>   System.IO.Packaging.PackagePart.GetStream(FileMode mode, FileAccess
>   access)    at System.IO.Packaging.PackagePart.GetStream()    at
>   System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(Object component, Uri
>   resourceLocator)    at
>   InfoCenter.Views.Main.MainView.InitializeComponent() in
>   D:\Workspace\Visual Studio\MT Info Center WPF\Info
>   Center\Views\Main\MainView.xaml:line 1    at
>   InfoCenter.Views.Main.MainView..ctor() in D:\Workspace\Visual
>   Studio\MT Info Center WPF\Info Center\Views\Main\MainView.xaml.cs:line
>   21    at InfoCenter.App.OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e) in
>   D:\Workspace\Visual Studio\MT Info Center WPF\Info
>   Center\App.xaml.cs:line 57    at
>   System.Windows.Application.<.ctor>b__1_0(Object unused)    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate
>   callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source,
>   Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler) 
>   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(Object
>   state)    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)    at
>   MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.Run(CulturePreservingExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32
>   msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)    at
>   MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam,
>   IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)    at
>   MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate
>   callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source,
>   Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler) 
>   at
>   System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority
>   priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32
>   numArgs)    at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd,
>   Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)    at
>   MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame
>   frame)    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
>
>   at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)    at
>   System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)    at
>   System.Windows.Application.Run(Window window)    at
>   System.Windows.Application.Run()    at InfoCenter.App.Main() in
>   D:\Workspace\Visual Studio\MT Info Center WPF\Info
>   Center\obj\Debug\App.g.cs:line 51*

Here is some of the code:

App.xaml

```
<!--ANCHOR: Updater-->
<updater:SingleInstanceApplication x:Class="InfoCenter.App"
                                   x:Name="App"
                                   xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                                   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                                   xmlns:updater="clr-namespace:InfoCenter.Updater">
    <Application.Resources>
    </Application.Resources>
</updater:SingleInstanceApplication>
```

App.xaml.cs:

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    if (PreProcessor.Prod)
        Dispatcher.UnhandledException += OnDispatcherUnhandledException;

    base.OnStartup(e);

    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetPrincipalPolicy(PrincipalPolicy.WindowsPrincipal);

    var app = new MainView { ShowInTaskbar = false, Topmost = true }
    var context = new MainViewModel();
    app.DataContext = context;
    app.Show();
}
```

Other info:
- We deploy using ClickOnce.
- The app have some background tasks that will keep running. It look like it just runs without a view.
- We use MVVM pattern.

If I am missing some information, don't hesitate to ask!

Comment: I don't get it. Which method are you using to localize your text? Cause as far as i know the common way is to just add a Resource.yourlanguege.resx dictionary in your project and you should have any problem

Comment: Vi have resource files named _Localization.da-DK.xml_ and _Localization.en-US.xml_. Vi have a class that deserializes one and stuffs it in some variables. But this code is not the problem. While completely removed, the problem persists.

Comment: Did you set your StartUp uri in app.xaml?

Comment: I did not, but doing so did not help. This will also bypass some code I have in my OnStartup override.

Comment: Are youn setting CultureInfo somewhere? check this https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/648517/Error-Resolved-IOException-Cannot-locate-resource

Comment: Aha! Thanks for the link! `<UICulture>en-US</UICulture>` was set to _da-DK_. Uncommenting `[assembly: NeutralResourcesLanguage("en-US", UltimateResourceFallbackLocation.Satellite)]` and changing it to _da-DK_ fixed the problem. If you put it in as an answer, I will mark it as solution.

Comment: @ Niksen glad that it helped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was a problem regarding the Culture Info, since you have added this line in your resource file

```
<UICulture>en-US</UICulture>
```

Following  [this post](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/648517/Error-Resolved-IOException-Cannot-locate-resource) you should be able to solve your problem uncommenting this line

```
[assembly: NeutralResourcesLanguage("en-US", UltimateResourceFallbackLocation.Satellite)]
```

in your assembly.info.cs